# Convexity of $x^2f(x)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Given a function $f$ which is decreasing and convex on $(0,\infty)$, is it possible to find a simple condition on $f$ such that 
\begin{equation}
2f(x) + 4xf^\prime(x) + x^2f^{\prime\prime}(x) \geq 0.
\end{equation}
By integrating I worked out that this is equivalent to requiring that $x^2f(x)$ is convex but I would like to express it as a condition on $f$ only. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused by this.  Suppose $f$ satisfies your inequality. We must have $f(0)\geq 0$  Then I can choose $g(x) = f(x) - (f(0)+1)$.  Then $x\mapsto x^2g(x)$ is still convex but $g(0) = -1$ which breaks the inequality. Have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @Tim - can you prove that $x^2g(x)$ is still convex? It doesn't seem obvious to me. Keep in mind that $x^2g(x)=x^2f(x)-(f(0)+1)x^2$, so it requires the assumption that $(f(0)+1)x^2$ is... let's say "not as convex" at any point as $x^2f(x)$.

Comment: Good point.  You can ignore my last comment on the grounds that I'm an idiot.

Comment: @angry_pacifist: I think you'll find that "$x^2f(x)$ is convex" and the inequality are the same statement (the left side of the inequality is literally $(x^2f(x))''$, so it's stating that the second derivative of $x^2f(x)$ is positive, a condition of convexity). I'm not sure what sort of "simple condition on $f$" you would be expecting other than this.

Comment: @GlenO: Yes, the 2 statements are equivalent if $f$ is twice differentiable. I was wondering if it is possible to find some simple sufficient conditions on $f$ that fulfil $2f + 4xf^\prime + x^2f^{\prime\prime} \geq 0$.For instance, take $f$ positive, and such that $\left|\frac{f^\prime(x)- f^\prime(y)}{f(x)-f(y)}\right|\geq 1$. Then the inequality is satisfied on $(1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

As $f(x)$ is convex, we have
$$
f''\geq 0
$$
As $f(x)$ is decreasing, we also have
$$
f'< 0
$$

These are applying when $x>0$. As we seek a sufficient condition, let us simply require that
$$
\frac12f(x)+xf'(x)\geq 0
$$
which, given that $f''\geq 0$, means that the given inequality will be satisfied if this inequality is satisfied. Dividing by $\sqrt{x}$, we have
$$
\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}f(x)+\sqrt{x}f'(x)\geq 0
$$
This reveals the required substitution - let $\sqrt{x}f(x)=g(x)$. This allows us to state our inequality as
$$
g'(x)\geq 0
$$
This may then be stated in a different way, as
$$
g(y)\geq g(x) \qquad \text{when} \qquad y> x
$$
Substituting back to our original function, we have
$$
\sqrt{y}f(y)\geq \sqrt{x}f(x) \qquad \text{when} \qquad y> x
$$
This is a *sufficient* condition - if this condition is satisfied, then the required inequality will be satisfied, too. It does not necessarily mean that all functions that satisfy the required inequality will also satisfy this condition.

Now for a necessary condition: Suppose that there is a value of $x=a$ for which $f(a)=0$, and $f'(a)<0$ (and thus, as it is decreasing, all values $x>a$ will have $f(x)<0$). Now, we wish to show that there exists an $x$ such that $x^2f(x)<(x-a)a^2f'(a)$ (that is, a value of $x$ such that $x^2f(x)$ lies below the tangent line drawn at $x=a$, thus making the function non-convex).

Suppose otherwise - that is,
$$
x^2 f(x)\geq(x-a)a^2f'(a)
$$
Now, we have that
$$
f(x)\geq \left(\frac1x-\frac{a}{x^2}\right)a^2f'(a)
$$
But
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} \left(\frac1x-\frac{a}{x^2}\right)a^2f'(a) = 0
$$
Therefore,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) \geq 0
$$
But $f(x)$ is decreasing - therefore, $f(x)\geq 0$ again. This contradicts the assumption that there exists an $a$ such that $f(a)=0$, and thus, if $f(a)=0$ for some $a$, there must exist a point $x>a$ at which the function is concave.

This is a *necessary* condition - in order for the required inequality to be satisfied, this condition must be satisfied, but it does not guarantee that the required inequality be satisfied.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are saying that it is enough to have $f\geq 0$ in order to have $x^2f(x)$ convex. However, take $f(x) = 1/x^{3/2}$, which is strictly positive, decreasing and convex for all $x>0$. Then $x^2f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ which is not convex and provides a counterexample. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the flaw - when I apply the integral, I falsely assume that it works the other way, when it doesn't. I'll try to fix the error.

Comment: @angry_pacifist: OK, I've fixed the reasoning. It's not quite as neat, because it's not a single "necessary and sufficient condition", but it provides one nice condition that is sufficient, and one that is necessary. Note that, regarding your prior edit of my answer, you incorrectly switched from sufficient to necessary - it's sufficient if the condition guarantees the desired result, it's necessary if the desired result guarantees the condition.

Comment: you are right, I think it works now. This is also consistent with the previous counterexample since, $\left(\sqrt{x}\frac{1}{x^{1.5}}\right)^\prime < 0$. Thanks.